# backstretch slideshow is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-backstretch

Can not understand about backstretch.

tried like 5 hours. I am beginner.Can you look at the code and tell 
me what is wrong? And can you people tell me about 
good simple plugin for slideshow of background img. I need slideshow 
inside a division so that i can change it's size and put it anywhere 
i like.Tried to find solution by searching google and this website but
failed.

```
$(".abcd").backstretch(["https://i.imgur.com/LquRrwI.jpg","https://i.imgur.com/zVk2HHq.jpg"] {duration: 10000, fade: 750});
```

https://codepen.io/roymahdi/pen/OxyWXy/

Comment: "Not working" doesn't mean anything specific. Please see: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a comma `,` before {duration: 10000, fade: 750}